# data getting stored in wrong manner in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

This is my Data which i want to save in core data.

```
"exclusions":[
[
{
"facility_id":"1",
"options_id":"4"
},
{
"facility_id":"2",
"options_id":"6"
}
],
[
{
"facility_id":"1",
"options_id":"3"
},
{
"facility_id":"3",
"options_id":"12"
}
],
[
{
"facility_id":"2",
"options_id":"7"
},
{
"facility_id":"3",
"options_id":"12"
}
]
]
```

When ever i save my data it is getting sorted based on "facility_id".

I am not able to understand how it is changing my data order.

This is SS of my core data model ->  http://prntscr.com/kac68u

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed sort order when saving and it’s not relevant, you sort your data using sort descriptors when fetching it.